# Как отсортировать список в treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter

Имею код программы, который выводит данные из xml файла в treeview.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class App:

  def __init__(self, root):

    try:
      with open('FileInfo.xml') as f:
        read_data = f.read()
        ansi = read_data.encode('ansi')
      rootNode = ET.fromstring(ansi)

      self.tree = Treeview(root)
      self.tree.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
      self.tree.heading('#0', text=rootNode.get('displayName'), anchor='w')
      self.walk_dict(rootNode)
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)

  def walk_dict(self, d, depth=0, parent=""):
    for child in d:
      if(child.tag == 'folder'):
          item = self.tree.insert(parent, 'end', None, text=child.get('displayName'))

      elif(child.tag == 'element'):
          item = self.tree.insert(parent, 'end', None, text=child.get('file'))

      if child.__len__() > 0:
          self.walk_dict(child, depth + 1, parent=item)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x600")
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Xml файл с содержимым:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<library displayName="MyLibrary">
    <description />
    <folder displayName="9_">
        <folder displayName="9_">
            <element displayName="9_" file="9_.kdw" />
            <description>Description.</description>
            <element displayName="1_" file="1_.kdw" />
            <element displayName="я_" file="я_.kdw" />
            <element displayName="а_" file="а_.kdw" />
            <element displayName="z_" file="z_.kdw" />
            <element displayName="a_" file="a_.kdw" />
        </folder>
        <folder displayName="1_">
            <element displayName="9_" file="9_.kdw" />
        </folder>
        <folder displayName="я_">
            <element displayName="9_" file="9_.kdw" />
        </folder>
        <folder displayName="а_">
            <element displayName="9_" file="9_.kdw" />
        </folder>
        <folder displayName="z_">
            <element displayName="9_" file="9_.kdw" />
        </folder>
        <folder displayName="a_">
            <element displayName="9_" file="9_" />
        </folder>
    </folder>
    <folder displayName="1_">
    <element displayName="9_" file="9_.kdw" />
    </folder>
    <folder displayName="я_">
        <element displayName="9_" file="9_.kdw" />
    </folder>
    <folder displayName="а_">
        <element displayName="9_" file="9_" />
    </folder>
    <folder displayName="z_">
        <element displayName="9_" file="9_.kdw" />
    </folder>
    <folder displayName="a_">
        <element displayName="9_" file="9_.kdw" />
  </folder>
    <element displayName="9_" file="9_.kdw" />
    <element displayName="1_" file="1_.kdw" />
    <element displayName="я_" file="я_.kdw" />
    <element displayName="а_" file="а_.kdw" />
    <element displayName="z_" file="z_.kdw" />
    <element displayName="a_" file="a_.kdw" />
</library>
```

Нужно отсортировать все директории и файлы. 1-999..., a-z, а-я.

Судя по всему сортировка должна быть где-то здесь...

```
ansi = read_data.encode('ansi')
....
rootNode = ET.fromstring(ansi)
```

Вот что я получаю на данный момент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишем метод для сортировки:

```
  @staticmethod
  def sort_by_attr(node, tags, attr):
    return sorted(filter(lambda x: x.tag in tags, node), key=lambda child: child.get(attr))
```

Если требуется просто отсортировать, то достаточно использовать его так:

```
  def walk_dict(self, d, depth=0, parent=""):
    for child in self.sort_by_attr(d, ('folder', 'element'), "displayName"):
       ...
```

Правда файлы будут вперемешку с папками.

Если папки надо вынести в начало, то так:

```
  def walk_dict(self, d, depth=0, parent=""):
    for child in self.sort_by_attr(d, ('folder'), "displayName"):
      item = self.tree.insert(parent, 'end', None, text=child.get('displayName'))
      if len(child) > 0:
        self.walk_dict(child, depth + 1, parent=item)
    for child in self.sort_by_attr(d, ('element'), "file"):
      item = self.tree.insert(parent, 'end', None, text=child.get('file'))
```